# Trying to retrieve the x-value from a x-coordinate on a d3.js SVG graph

Tags: d3.js

I'm a little stuck on something, and I was hoping that maybe someone could point me in the correct direction for the solution. Running searches on Google isn't helping me out much due to the wording of the searches.

What I'm trying to do is get the 'value' of an x-position on a graph. On my graph, my x-axis is made up of dates. So, if I know the plotted x co-ordinate point on the graph is 200 for example, I'd like the date label for x-position 200. There are lots of tutorials and examples that demonstrate how to retrieve the x-coordinate (200), but not the x-coordinate value (Date object for x-position 200).

What I'm ultimately going to do is build a user notes feature which allows the user to select an x-position on the graph and then make a note at that point. I'll need to store an object for that note containing the x and y value of their coordinates, and since the points on the graph are mapped and remapped by applying a Date object to .x, I need to get the Date for any points I plot on the graph so they can be recorded and re-applied, and even moved if the user decides to move the note tool around.

Anyway, I'm kind of looking for a way to reverse-engineer this...

```
function getDateX(x, data) {
    var dateX = x(data.Date);
    return dateX;
}
```

...but instead of, in this case, getting the x-coordinate position back, get the Date back based on the provided x-coordinate position.

Any pointers toward the solution that you could provide me with would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Each scale has an .invert() function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368096/d3-finding-graph-y-coordinate-with-mouseover provided answers to a similar question

Answer (score 6):

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0,200])
          .range([new Date("2000-01-01"), new Date("2001-01-01")]);

new Date(x(150))

// Sun Oct 01 2000 21:00:00 GMT+0900 (東京 (標準時))
```

Or, if you already have a scale which is Date -> number

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
          .range([0,200])
          .domain([new Date("2000-01-01"), new Date("2001-01-01")]);

x.invert(150)

// Sun Oct 01 2000 21:00:00 GMT+0900 (東京 (標準時))
```