# Change X and Y coordinate values on mouseover event in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I created mouseover function to show x and y co-ordinate for my line graph. I want to show correct x and y co-ordinate position at the time of mouse over event. Can someone please help me find out how to rewrite the tooltip function to show correct x and y co-ordinate. Thank you.

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
     .data(data)
//    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text(function(d){console.log((d.Mass+ ","+ d.Intensity));return (d.Mass+ ","+ d.Intensity);});
```

The link for line graph is at following location.

http://jsbin.com/nipeko/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368096/d3-finding-graph-y-coordinate-with-mouseover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
.on("mouseover", function(){
   var pos = d3.mouse(this);
   tooltip.text(xScale.invert(pos[0]).toFixed(1) + ' , ' + yScale.invert(pos[1]).toFixed(1));
   return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
 })
```

Updated [code](http://jsbin.com/bimugexogo/1/edit?js,output).